# how to make text over images in a row using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Now it is not responsive, the two images should be in one row. I want to make text like painting and photography over these images. how can it be possible?

```css
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9%;
  left: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Myriad Pro regular;
  font-size: 15.31px;
}

.caption1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -51px;
  left: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Myriad Pro regular;
  font-size: 15.31px;
}

.imageandtext {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">
  <figure>

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" class="img-thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Painting</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/?r" class="img-thumbnail">
      <div class="caption1">
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your HTML and CSS a bit

```css
.image_and_text {
  position: relative;
}

.image_and_text .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 image_and_text">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Painting</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 image_and_text">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/?r" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cover your image and caption  text in a relative element

```
figure{
    position: relative;
}
```

Check the below snippet -

```css
figure{
 position: relative;
}
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Myriad Pro regular;
  font-size: 15.31px;
}

.caption1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Myriad Pro regular;
  font-size: 15.31px;
}

.imageandtext {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">
   <figure>
     <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200,c_crop,g_center/fat_cat.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
     <div class="caption">
       <p>Painting</p>
     </div>
    </figure>
    <figure>
     <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
       <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200,c_crop,g_center/fat_cat.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
       <div class="caption1">
         <p>Photography</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update css part

```
    figure {
      display: flex; /*For image lineup */
    }
   .imageandtext, .image_grid {
      position: relative;
    }

   .imageandtext, .image_grid {
       position: relative;
       margin:5px;
    }
```

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9%;/*Change as your need*/
  left: 52px;/*Change as your need*/
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Myriad Pro regular;
  font-size: 15.31px;
}

.caption1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px; /*Change as your need*/
  left: 11px; /*Change as your need*/
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Myriad Pro regular;
  font-size: 15.31px;
}

.imageandtext,
.image_grid {
  position: relative;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" class="img-thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Painting</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/?r" class="img-thumbnail">
      <div class="caption1">
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```